# How can I stop jQuery functions interfering with each other?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two separate (but similar) bits of jQuery code. They both work, but interfere with each other. How do I properly format these functions to be unique and stop them from affecting each other?

> **Code block 1:**

```
$('#share-email').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#socialbox-" + $(this).attr('rel')).load('<?php echo site_url();?>club/sendtofriend/' + $(this).attr('rel'));
    return false;
});

$().ajaxSend(function (r, s) {
    $(".social-share-container").fadeOut('fast');
});

$().ajaxStop(function (r, s) {
    $(".social-share-container").fadeIn('fast');
});
```

> **Code block 2:**

```
$('.djlink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#djinfo").load($(this).attr('href'), Cufon.refresh);
    return false;
});

$().ajaxSend(function (r, s) {
    $("#djinfo").fadeOut('fast');
});

$().ajaxStop(function (r, s) {
    $("#djinfo").fadeIn('fast');
});
```

The part of the code that appears to be overlapping is the ajax send/stop part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correctly guessing what you're trying to do, something like this should solve it:

```
    $('#share-email').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#socialbox-" + $(this).attr('rel')).fadeOut('fast').load('<?php echo site_url();?>club/sendtofriend/' + $(this).attr('rel'), function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast')
        });
        return false;
    });


    $('.djlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#djinfo").fadeOut('fast').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            Cufon.refresh();
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: That does effect the correct elements, but I do need to send receive the ajax properly. Doing this way fades in the element before the ajax is properly loaded.

Comment: Got you, amending the answer.

Comment: I think executing the fadeIn part in load's callback function should do it properly, let me know how it goes